# ICommandHandler/IQueryHandler with async/await

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, cqrs, c#-5.0, simple-injector

## EDITH says (tl;dr)

I went with a variant of the suggested solution; keeping all `ICommandHandler`s and `IQueryHandler`s potentially aynchronous and returning a resolved task in synchronous cases. Still, I don't want to use `Task.FromResult(...)` all over the place so I defined an extension method for convenience:

```cs
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static Task<TResult> AsTaskResult<TResult>(this TResult result)
    {
        // Or TaskEx.FromResult if you're targeting .NET4.0 
        // with the Microsoft.BCL.Async package
        return Task.FromResult(result); 
    }
}

// Usage in code ...
using TaskExtensions;
class MySynchronousQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<MyQuery, bool>
{
    public Task<bool> Handle(MyQuery query)
    {
        return true.AsTaskResult();
    }
}

class MyAsynchronousQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<MyQuery, bool>
{
    public async Task<bool> Handle(MyQuery query)
    {
        return await this.callAWebserviceToReturnTheResult();
    }
}
```

It's a pity that C# isn't [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org) ... yet 8-). Really smells like an application of [Arrows](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/). Anyway, hope this helps anyone. Now to my original question :-)

## Introduction

Hello there!

For a project I'm currently designing an application architecture in C# (.NET4.5, C#5.0, ASP.NET MVC4). With this question I hope to get some opinions about some issues I stumbled upon trying to incorporate `async/await`. Note: this is quite a lengthy one :-)

My solution structure looks like this:

- `MyCompany.Contract` (Commands/Queries and common interfaces)
- `MyCompany.MyProject` (Contains the business logic and command/query handlers)
- `MyCompany.MyProject.Web` (The MVC web frontend)

I read up on maintainable architecture and Command-Query-Separation and found these posts very helpful:

- [Meanwhile on the query side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)
- [Meanwhile on the command side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)
- [Writing highly maintainable WCF services](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95)

So far I've got my head around the `ICommandHandler`/`IQueryHandler` concepts and dependency injection (I'm using [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org) - it's really dead simple).

## The Given Approach

The approach of the articles above suggests using POCOs as commands/queries and describes dispatchers of these as implementations of the following handler interfaces:

```cs
interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}

interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

In a MVC Controller you'd use this as follows:

```cs
class AuthenticateCommand
{
    // The token to use for authentication
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string SomeResultingSessionId { get; set; }
}

class AuthenticateController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<AuthenticateCommand> authenticateUser;

    public AuthenticateController(ICommandHandler<AuthenticateCommand> authenticateUser) 
    {
        // Injected via DI container
        this.authenticateUser = authenticateUser;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string externalToken)
    {
        var command = new AuthenticateCommand 
        { 
            Token = externalToken 
        };
        this.authenticateUser.Handle(command);

        var sessionId = command.SomeResultingSessionId;
        // Do some fancy thing with our new found knowledge
    }
}
```

Some of my observations concerning this approach:

1. In pure [CQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) only queries should return values while commands should be, well only commands. In reality it is more convenient for commands to return values instead of issuing the command and later doing a query for the thing the command should have returned in the first place (e.g. database ids or the like). That's why [the author suggested](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=93) putting a return value into the command POCO.
2. It is not very obvious what is returned from a command, in fact it *looks* like the command is a fire and forget type of thing until you eventually encounter the weird result property being accessed after the handler has run plus the command now knows about it's result
3. The handlers *have* to be synchronous for this to work - queries as well as commands. As it turns out with C#5.0 you can inject `async/await` powered handlers with the help of your favorite DI container, but the compiler doesn't know about that at compile time so the MVC handler will fail miserably with an exception telling you that the method returned before all asynchronous tasks finished executing.

Of course you can mark the MVC handler as `async` and this is what this question is about.

## Commands Returning Values

I thought about the given approach and made changes to the interfaces to address issues 1. and 2. in that I added an `ICommandHandler` that has an explicit result type - just like the `IQueryHandler`. This still violates CQS but at least it is plain obvious that these commands return some sort of value with the additional benefit of not having to clutter the command object with a result property:

```cs
interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

Naturally one could argue that when you have the same interface for commands and queries why bother? But I think it's worth naming them differently - just looks cleaner to my eyes.

## My Preliminary Solution

Then I thought hard of the 3rd issue at hand ... some of my command/query handlers need to be asynchronous (e.g. issuing a `WebRequest` to another web service for authentication) others don't. So I figured it would be best to design my handlers from the ground up for `async/await` - which of course bubbles up to the MVC handlers even for handlers that are in fact synchronous:

```cs
interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
{
    Task<TResult> Handle(TQuery query);
}

interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    Task Handle(TCommand command);
}

interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>
{
    Task<TResult> Handle(TCommand command);
}

class AuthenticateCommand
{
    // The token to use for authentication
    public string Token { get; set; }

    // No more return properties ...
}
```

AuthenticateController:

```
class AuthenticateController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<AuthenticateCommand, string> authenticateUser;

    public AuthenticateController(ICommandHandler<AuthenticateCommand, 
        string> authenticateUser) 
    {
        // Injected via DI container
        this.authenticateUser = authenticateUser;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string externalToken)
    {
        var command = new AuthenticateCommand 
        { 
            Token = externalToken 
        };
        // It's pretty obvious that the command handler returns something
        var sessionId = await this.authenticateUser.Handle(command);

        // Do some fancy thing with our new found knowledge
    }
}
```

Although this solves my problems - obvious return values, all handlers can be async - it hurts my brain to put `async` on a thingy that isn't async just because. There are several drawbacks I see with this:

- The handler interfaces are not as neat as I wanted them to be - the `Task<...>` thingys to my eyes are very verbose and at first sight obfuscate the fact that I only want to return something from a query/command
- The compiler warns you about not having an appropriate `await` within synchronous handler implementations (I want to be able to compile my `Release` with `Warnings as Errors`) - you can overwrite this with a pragma ... yeah ... well ...
- I could omit the `async` keyword in these cases to make the compiler happy but in order to implement the handler interface you would have to return some sort of `Task` explicitly - that's pretty ugly
- I could supply synchronous and asynchronous versions of the handler interfaces (or put all of them in one interface bloating the implementation) but my understanding is that, ideally, the consumer of a handler shouldn't be aware of the fact that a command/query handler is sync or async as this is a cross cutting concern. What if I need to make a formerly synchronous command async? I'd have to change every consumer of the handler potentially breaking semantics on my way through the code.
- On the other hand the *potentially*-async-handlers-approach would even give me the ability to change sync handlers to be async by decorating them with the help of my DI container

Right now I don't see a *best* solution to this ... I'm at a loss.

Anyone having a similar problem and an elegant solution I didn't think of?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Async and await don't mix perfectly with traditional OOP. I have a blog series on the subject; you may find the [post on async interfaces](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-1-inheritance-and-interfaces.html) helpful in particular (though I don't cover anything you haven't already discovered).

The design problems around `async` are extremely similar to the ones around `IDisposable`; it's a breaking change to add `IDisposable` to an interface, so you need to know whether any possible implementation may *ever* be disposable (an implementation detail). A parallel problem exists with `async`; you need to know whether any possible implementation may *ever* be asynchronous (an implementation detail).

For these reasons, I view `Task`-returning methods on an interface as "possibly asynchronous" methods, just like an interface inheriting from `IDisposable` means it "possibly owns resources."

The best approach I know of is:

- Define any methods that are possibly-asynchronous with an asynchronous signature (returning `Task`/`Task<T>`).
- Return `Task.FromResult(...)` for synchronous implementations. This is more proper than an `async` without an `await`.

This approach is almost exactly what you're already doing. A more ideal solution may exist for a purely functional language, but I don't see one for C#.

Comment: Thanks, the concepts are in fact pretty similar ... I added my personal solution to the question for convenience

Answer (score 13):

You state:

> the consumer of a handler shouldn't be aware of the fact that a
>   command/query handler is sync or async as this is a cross cutting
>   concern

Stephen Clearly already touched this a bit, but async is not a cross-cutting concern (or at least not the way it's implemented in .NET). Async is an architectural concern since you have to decide up front to use it or not, and it completely chances all your application code. It changes your interfaces and it's therefore impossible to 'sneak' this in, without the application to know about it.

Although .NET made async easier, as you said, it still hurts your eyes and mind. Perhaps it just needs mental training, but I'm really wondering whether it is all worth the trouble to go async for most applications.

Either way, prevent having two interfaces for command handlers. You must pick one, because having two separate interfaces will force you to duplicate all your decorators that you want to apply to them and duplicates your DI configation. So either have an interface that returns `Task` and uses output properties, or go with `Task<TResut>` and return some sort of `Void` type in case there is no return type.

As you can imagine (the articles you point at are mine) my personal preference is to have a `void Handle` or `Task Handle` method, since with commands, the focus is not on the return value and when having a return value, you will end up having a duplicate interface structure as the queries have:

```
public interface ICommand<TResult> { }

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult> 
    where TCommand : ICommand<TResult> 
{ 
    Task<TResult> Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

Without the `ICommand<TResult>` interface and the generic type constraint, you will be missing compile time support. This is something I explained in [Meanwhile... on the query side of my architecture](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/queries/)

Comment: Instead of returning Task<TResult> from the command handler
can't we just return TResult ? exactly what you did in your article. But to support asyn we can design Command as 

`public interface SaveUserDetailCommand:ICommand<Task<UserProfile>>{

}`
so handler looks

`SaveUserDetailCommandHandler:ICommandHandler<SaveUserDetailCommand,Task<UserProfile>>
{
 public Task<UserProfile> Handle(SaveUserDetailCommand cmd)
{

}
}`
 from the controller we can then do, await mediator.execute(command);
Do you think any problem with this approach ??

Comment: @Steven I think you're right with the single `ICommandHandler` interface. I implemented quite a bit with this pattern and there is indeed plenty of duplicated stuff for supporting both abstractions... maybe I'm going at it all wrong and my commands that return data (and on top of that need validation on this return data) are queries in reality. I'm not so sure about this: would you consider converting something (Fetch data from DB with user credentials->Save into Excel-Filestream->Download file) a command or a query? thx

Comment: @Int3ὰ: From a consuming perspective, this will work fine, but there will certainly be problems with that approach. You still can't apply a generic decorator around these handlers, because the decorator must know whether the return type is async or not. Just imagine a simple logging decorator that wraps the decoratee in a try-finally and logs the duration of the operation. When applied to a async handler, the duration of the operation will always become close to zero, since the decorator will only work correctly when it applies a `ContinueWith` delegate to the returned `Task`.

Comment: @vanhelgen: "Fetch data from DB with user credentials->Save into Excel-Filestream->Download file" will definately be a query; not a command. There's no business operation, nothing changes in your application (apart from temporarily saving some excel file).

Comment: @Steven: I just did the refactoring and now it's just plain obvious ... stupid me and thank you! There is some logging involved but that is not vital to the business operation itself

Comment: @vanhelgen: That's not stupid at all. It takes time to train your brain to see those patterns. But once you mastered this, you'll be like Neo in the Matrix. It's [decorators... decorators everywhere](http://www.quickmeme.com/p/3vw5iu) ;-)

Comment: @Steven Actually, I could not understand at first what you were saying, Then I tried with the Duration Logger decoration, it produced result close to 0 second even though the operation actually took 3 sec .I refactored my code to return Task<TResponse> I just worked as excepted. But one question. Creating Task For each synchronized result does not affect performance?

Comment: @Int3ὰ: Sorry for the delay. I had to consult [an expert on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387870/blueling) about this. The use of `Task.FromResult` will force extra pressure on the garbage collector, but should in most systems -as far as we can see- not have any noticeable impact.

Answer (score 12):

I created a project for just this - I wound up not splitting commands and queries, instead using request/response and pub/sub - https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR

```
public interface IMediator
{
    TResponse Send<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> request);
    Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TResponse>(IAsyncRequest<TResponse> request);
    void Publish<TNotification>(TNotification notification) where TNotification : INotification;
    Task PublishAsync<TNotification>(TNotification notification) where TNotification : IAsyncNotification;
}
```

For the case where commands don't return results, I used a base class that returned a Void type (Unit for functional folks). This allowed me to have a uniform interface for sending messages that have responses, with a null response being an explicit return value.

As someone exposing a command, you explicitly opt-in to being asynchronous in your definition of the request, rather than forcing everyone to be async.

Answer (score 5):

Not really an answer, but for what it's worth, i came to the exact same conclusions, and a very similar implementation.

My `ICommandHandler<T>` and `IQueryHandler<T>` return `Task` and `Task<T>` respectively. In case of a synchronous implementation i use `Task.FromResult(...)`. I also had some *handler decorators in place (like for logging) and as you can imagine these also needed to be changed.

For now, i decided to make 'everything' potentially await-able, and got into the habit of using `await` in conjunction with my dispatcher (finds handler in ninject kernel and calls handle on it).

I went async all the way, also in my webapi/mvc controllers, with few exceptions. In those rare cases i use `Continuewith(...)` and `Wait()` to wrap things in a synchronous method.

Another, related frustration i have is that MR recommends to name methods with the *Async suffix in case thay are (duh) async. But as this is an implementation decision i (for now) decided to stick with `Handle(...)` rather than `HandleAsync(...)`.

It is definitely not a satisfactory outcome and i'm also looking for a better solution.